# How to return the doubly linked list and remove leaves of the tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, recursion

I was working on a SPOJ-like task. The objective was to find the leaves in the binary tree (not necessarily a BST), delete them from the tree and return them as a kind of doubly linked list, using the same structure - TreeNode and no additional imports. For example if the nodes 2, 4 and 3 are deleted from the tree, function returns the firs non-null element of the list: null <- 2 <-> 4 <-> 3 -> null. TreeNode has a value and left and right pointers.

I used recursion and nullified the leaves to delete them from the tree and recreated them in a list. To keep adding element to the end of the list efficient, I held the pointer to the last element of the list. This created a well known problem of altering the object passed to the function. Here is my code:

```
public TreeNode getLeaves(TreeNode root)
{
    if(root == null)
        return null;

    TreeNode start = new TreeNode(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    TreeNode[] end = {start};
    getLeaves(root, start, end);
    return start;
}

private void getLeaves(TreeNode root, TreeNode start, TreeNode[] end)
{
    if(root == null)
        return;

    if(root.left == null && root.right == null)
    {
        addToList(root, start, end);
        root = null;
        return;
    }
    getLeaves(root.left, start, end);
    getLeaves(root.right, start, end);
}

private void addToList(TreeNode element, TreeNode start, TreeNode[] end)
{
    if(end[0].value != Integer.MIN_VALUE)
    {
        TreeNode t = new TreeNode (element.value);
        end[0].right = t;
        t.left = end[0];
        end[0] = t;
    }
    else
    {
        start.value = element.value;
    }
}
```

Deleting the leaves from tree does not work, but the list is returned properly. However, setting the value of "start" TreeNode to minimal int value instead of using null reference bugs me, and so does using the array. Using Atomic Reference would make it more messy IMHO. I'm quite sure that there is a method to do it in much more elegant way (and to delete the leaves properly), probably by changing the approach of assigning start and end TreeNodes. I feel that something is wrong with my approach and/or understanding of the way it all works. Could you please help me turning it into a neat piece of code and explain my bads?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your second `GetLeaves` function. The statement `root = null;` sets the value of the *local variable* `root` to null, but its parent will keep the reference to the leaf.

You will have a much easier time if you add a method `bool isLeaf()` to `TreeNode`. I modified your code to something I think might work.

```
private bool isLeaf()
{
    // This method should be in TreeNode
    return left == null && right == null;
}
// Also, TreeNode should have an Add(TreeNode) method

public TreeNode getLeaves(TreeNode root)
{
    if( root == null )  // check if the whole tree is empty
        return null;  // return something relevant here
    else if( root.isLeaf() )
        return root;  //cannot remove this leaf, unfortunately
    TreeNode leaves = new TreeNode()
    getLeaves(root, leaves);
    return leaves;
}
private void getLeaves(TreeNode current, TreeNode leaves)
{
    // current is guaranteed to be non-null and not a leaf itself.
    if( current.left.isLeaf() ) {
        leaves.add(current.left);
        current.left = null;
    } else {
        getLeaves(current.left, leaves);
    }
    if( current.right.isLeaf() ) {
        leaves.add(current.right);
        current.right = null;
    } else {
        getLeaves(current.right, leaves);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

David, you are 100% right. Thank you for helping. In case anyone is wondering, here is the most elegant solution I produced so far, including David's improvement. The only thing I'm not sure about is if the addToList method should be static or maybe it's more properly/universal to call it in element's context.

```
public TreeNode getLeaves(TreeNode root)
{
    if(root == null)
        return null;

    if(root.isLeaf())
        return root;

    TreeNode[] listEdges = {null, null};
    getLeaves(root, listEdges);
    return listEdges[0];
}

private void getLeaves(TreeNode root, TreeNode[] edges)
{
    if(root == null)
        return;

    if(root.left != null && root.left.isLeaf())
    {
        addToList(edges, root.left);
        root.left = null;
    }

    if(root.right != null && root.right.isLeaf())
    {
        addToList(edges, root.right);
        root.right = null;
    }
    getLeaves(root.left, edges);
    getLeaves(root.right, edges);
}

private static void addToList(TreeNode[] edges, TreeNode element)
{
    if(edges[1] != null)
    {
        edges[1].right = element;
        element.left = edges[1];
        edges[1] = element;
    }
    else
    {
        edges[0] = element;
        edges[1] = edges[0];
    }
}

public boolean isLeaf()
{
    return this.right == null && this.left == null;
}
```